# AWS S3 / Cloudfront deployment - certain paths aren't updating on static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

I'm fairly new to AWS and web dev - I have a simple static website at https://iveyfintechclub.ca

I recently refactored the code and made some changes to the project organization. I basically wiped the S3 bucket and reuploaded all new files and folders.

On CloudFront, I have `object caching` set to `use origin cache headers`:

[my CloudFront distribution behavior config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9nY1.png)

I also did an invalidation with /*.

On S3, I've set the metadata `Cache-Control` to `max-age=0` for all files.

Two problems are still eluding me:

1. The old bucket had a blank index.html which redirected to a
   nested HTML file. The new bucket has index.html as the landing page.
   When I attempt to visit the root URL, I get a 404 error as it still
   attempts to reach the old nested HTML path. This doesn't happen in incognito mode (browser cache issue).

<s>2. On the new landing page, I have a script file which is getting a 404
error as its looking for the file on its old path. Inspecting the HTML shows that the new path is in the client. This is happening in incognito mode too. All other resources are loading properly with
new paths, just this one is failing.</s>

I'm wondering if I just have to wait longer or if I'm still missing a configuration.

Comment: I resolved the second issue, it was unrelated to AWS but rather I had another script which didn't have the updated path.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874317/update-angular-app-on-aws-s3-cloudfront/62889254#62889254 i think you should use `/*` only instead of `/*. `  or try `/*` and `/index.html`

Comment: 1) Yes, that's a browser cache issue. Probably you downloaded the page before you added the Cache-Control header and the browser serves the original (cached) file